# What is the difference between copy and paste a file using command line terminal and GUI copy paste?

Tags: copy-paste

What is the difference between copy and paste a file using command line terminal and GUI copy paste ? Which one is fast ?
I think both are same because of same program will execute in background .

Comment: For windows there is no built in way to copy a file to the clipboard via the command line. If there were is would be an executable that used the standard shell API to do so.

Comment: GUI uses much more resources than a terminal , so in this way using a terminal would theoretically be quicker.

Comment: I did't get your answer. What am i asking is, in windows or linux ...i want to copy a directory from one directory to another. To do that i may use command line (cp command in linux or copy command in windows) or directly i can copy the directory by right click and paste in destination directory right click-> paste.
Now my question which process is fast/efficient. Or both are same?

Comment: maybe this question you fit better in SuperUser.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree terminal cp command works faster than GUI copy paste for large files.

Copy paste speed is also depends on available space on that destination drive.